# ASP.NET core 3.1 : UseWindowsService not setting content root as expected when publishing app with "produce single file"

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Created an ASP.NET core 3.1 application self-hosted within a windows service that uses HTTP.SYS and everything works fine. My **CreateHostBuilder** method starts as follows

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            // configure the app here.
            config.AddJsonFile("TEST.json");
        })
```

and the "TEST.json" file is correctly found and read from the content root folder (folder containing the windows service exe and other assemblies). If however I try publishing the application as a single file (with everything else the same)

[image]

loading of the "TEST.json" file fails with the following error as if content root was not being set to where the windows service executable resides (notice the file full path is expected to be 'C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Temp.net\TestNetCore\544bgjpl.0mf\TEST.json')

```
Application: TestNetCore.exe
CoreCLR Version: 4.700.20.26901
.NET Core Version: 3.1.5
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'TEST.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Temp\.net\TestNetCore\544bgjpl.0mf\TEST.json'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.HandleException(ExceptionDispatchInfo info)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at TestNetCore.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue, see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36065 for details. The issue is that AppContext.BaseDirectory isn't the original directory of the single-file exe, it's the directory into which the assemblies in the exe are extracted.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the file in Visual Studio, choose Properties option and select under "Copy to Output Directory" either "Copy Always"

Comment: I believe you completely misunderstood the described issue. It is not due to the json file non being there but to this file being expected in 'C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Temp.net\TestNetCore\544bgjpl.0mf\'